# Can we copy image from AWS S3 and write it into excel file (S3) without storing the data locally using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a jpeg image stored in s3.
My scenario is to create an excel file with that image inserted into it and load the excel file in the s3, without storing the excel file locally, using Python.

Comment: Do you want to use AWS Lambda for processing?

Comment: Not in Lamda, Python running locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using xlsxwriter package.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from io import BytesIO

boto_object = boto3.resource('s3',region_name='us-west-2', aws_access_key_id=AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY)

bucket_object = boto_object.Bucket(bucket_name=XXXX)

img_path = "images/data/sample_image.jpeg" # can be PNG, JPG or BMP

with BytesIO() as output:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:

        pandas_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sample_sheetname') #creating a sheet first
        image_obj = bucket_object.Object(img_path)
        response = image_obj.get()
        image_data = BytesIO(response['Body'].read())
        writer.sheets['sample_sheetname'].insert_image('A1',img_path, options = {'x_scale': 0.5,
                                                                   'y_scale': 0.5,
                                                                   'x_offset': 80,
                                                                   'y_offset': 10,'image_data':image_data}) #adding data to existing writer object
    data = output.getvalue()

bucket_object.put_object(Key='<path>/sample_output.xlsx', Body=data)
```

output:[image: output_image]